# Transaction management for J2SE applications

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the recommend transaction management technique to use for traditional JDBC connection transaction?

Typical disable of autocommit and commit management is a hassle for programmer to handle and rollback upon error spanning across several DAO.

Anyone can recommend on a better transaction management?

Comment: You can create saveopoints for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use JDBC directly, then you will need to live with the hassle of JDBC's transaction management features, that is `setAutoCommit(false)` and commit/rollback yourself.

If on the other hand, you use something higher level you can use higher level transaction management APIs. Hibernate, JDO and JPA all provide higher level transaction management mechanisms, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for spring jdbc/spring DAO. It gives you nice wrapper around JDBC